# Flask + uWSGI + Celery - How to start Celery as Daemon

Tags: python, flask, celery, uwsgi

I need help with start Celery daemon as smart-attach-daemon in uWSGI.ini file.

When i start Celery server from command line with command:
`/home/xxxxx/xxxxx/venv/bin/celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info --purge`
all works great.

But i don't know how start this server as daemon.

In documentation (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html)
are information:

Managing celery:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
socket = :3031
smart-attach-daemon = /tmp/celery.pid celery -A tasks worker --pidfile=/tmp/celery.pid
```

When i use:

```
smart-attach-daemon = %(base)aaa/celery.pid %(base)venv/bin/celery worker --pidfile=%(base)aaa/celery.pid --config=%(base)celeryconfig.py --workdir=%(base)app
```

in logs i see:

```
[uwsgi-daemons] found valid/active pidfile for "/home/xxxx/xxxxx/venv/bin/celery worker --pidfile=/home/xxxx/xxxxx/aaa/celery.pid --config=/home/xxxx/xxxxx/celeryconfig.py" (pid: 6901)
```

and Celery probably works fine.

But when i try add "-A" parameter for my worker:

```
smart-attach-daemon = %(base)aaa/celery.pid %(base)venv/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery --pidfile=%(base)aaa/celery.pid --config=%(base)celeryconfig.py --workdir=%(base)app
```

in log i see error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'celery_worker'
```

**Please, how i can start my Celery server with specific worker file?**

Or, how i can run command:

```
`/home/xxxxx/xxxxx/venv/bin/celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info --purge
```

as smart-attach-daemon?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your entire uwsgi config file?

I reckon it has something to do with uwsgi not properly recognizing your virtualenv directory/PYTHONPATH.

Try adding these to your uwsgi file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/xxxxx/xxxxx
home = /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/venv/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming your app.py is under the following **base** directory, this should work.

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/project
chdir = %(base)
module = app
pythonpath = %(base)
virtualenv = %(base)/venv
wsgi-file = %(base)/app.py
master = true
smart-attach-daemon = %(base)/tmp/celery.pid %(virtualenv)/bin/celery -A %(module).celery  worker --pidfile=%(base)/tmp/celery.pid
socket = %(base)/socket.sock
chmod-socket = 777
processes = 4
threads = 4
logto = %(base)/log/%n.log
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```